# .NET MVC 5 Ajax call unable to display javascript message after post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have made a form in my .NET MVC 5 application like following:

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "User", new { area = "UserSettings" }, new
  AjaxOptions
  {
  HttpMethod = "POST",
  OnSuccess = "alert('success');" //This will execute once the Ajax call is finished.

  }, null))
  {
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { placeholder = "Password", @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })<br />
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "float:right;" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PasswordConfirm, new { placeholder = "Confirm password", @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })<br />
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordConfirm, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "float:right;" })
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Password</button>
  }
```

And this is the method in controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("ChangePassword")]
        public ActionResult ChangePassword(UserSettings model)
        {
            using (var ctx = new myContextEntities())
            {
                var usr = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == User.Identity.Name);
                model.FirstName = usr.FirstName;
                model.LastName = usr.LastName;
                model.Email = usr.Email;
                model.Country = usr.Countries.CountryName;
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    usr.PasswordSalt = Helpers.PasswordHelper.CreateSalt(40);
                    usr.PasswordHash = Helpers.PasswordHelper.CreatePasswordHash(model.Password, usr.PasswordSalt);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                    return View("UserSettings",model);
                }
                return View("UserSettings", model);
            }
        }
```

Once the call is finished the page just refreshes, which shouldn't happen, but it should rather just display the success message ... ? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: make sure you have required js libraries added in the layout

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Which ones should I  have referenced for this option ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I have jquery included, jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js ...

Comment: did you included this--> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/

Comment: when using AJAX form, there is an option to say replace the inner form contents with the result, but that would mean you have to return PartialView from the action method.

Comment: @BrianMains if I do that, the whole page gets messed up =D

Comment: @BrianMains ..In this there is no problem in the return type both view and partial view is fine..he just need to include Unobtrusive Ajax .js file

Comment: @Suprajv when  I install the package , where does the file gets placed inside the project... ? In scripts folder perhaps?

Comment: @Suprajv works !!! U wanna answer so that I can accept ur answer?

Comment: Guys, one quick question. I have implemented now a function which displays message using jquery/javascript. Since I don't want to display just  simple alert popup(that'd be really stupid  from me)... How can I now  call this javascript function , which is defined in $document.ready() function ?

Comment: You can call javascript function no problem..in OnSuccess

Comment: @Suprajv http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764131/displaying-custom-message-on-net-ajax-post can u take a look , I've asked another question =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include Unobtrusive Ajax from the below Link

[Click Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/)

**Note**: Dont include both jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js, Include only one (js/min.js) file

The Below Files Does not Affect anything for you and your problem..

1.jquery.validate.min.js
2.jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

Answer (score 1):

For Ajax request, please create the following bundle in BundleConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
   //Create Your other bundles here

   //Create your Jquery validate bundle
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/Assets/jquery.validate.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/Assets/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/Assets/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"
            ));
}
```

In your _Layout.cshtml. Include this bundle as:

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

> Please make sure, jQuery must be included before this bundle. Please note that the paths to the javascript files are dummy in the above code block. You should give your own paths. The following JS files must be included:

1. jquery.validate.min.js
2. jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
3. jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js

Hope it helps :)