# Displaying custom message on .NET Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have .NET Ajax form like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "User", new { area = "UserSettings" }, new
AjaxOptions
{
HttpMethod = "POST",
OnSuccess = "( function() { ShowMessage('Password successfully changed.'); } )" //This will execute once the Ajax call is finished.
}, null))
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { placeholder = "Password", @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "float:right;" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PasswordConfirm, new { placeholder = "Confirm password", @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordConfirm, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "float:right;" })
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Password</button>
}
```

Note the OnSuccess part, if I do it like this, I can display a simple js alert popup like this:

```
OnSuccess = "Alert('OK');" //This will execute once the Ajax call is finished.
```

I have made a simple function in jQuery to display a more fancy message once the call is done like this:

```
  function ShowMessage(message) {
        $("#info").text(message);
        $("#info").fadeIn("slow");
        $('#info').show(0).delay(1500).fadeOut(400).hide(0);
    }
```

And if I try to do something like this:

```
  OnSuccess = "ShowMessage('OK');"
```

Nothing happens... What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. I've referenced all required files to make this work, including jQuery..

P.S. 2... The ShowMessage function is defined in $(document).ready function of the jquery... Perhaps I should post the entire function body to make this work or.. ?

Here is where I defined the function:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        function ShowMessage(message) {
            $("#info").text(message);
            $("#info").fadeIn("slow");
            $('#info').show(0).delay(1500).fadeOut(400).hide(0);
        }
  });
```

Supraj, this is the HTML for info tag:

```
   <div id="info" class="alert"><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></div>
```

Edit: Guys , I managed to do it like this:

```
OnSuccess = "$('#info').text('Success'); $('#info').fadeIn('slow'); $('#info').show(0).delay(1500).fadeOut(400).hide(0); " //This will execute once the Ajax call is finished.
```

But this looks really ugly... Is there any way I can multi-line this thing ?

Comment: Where did you place ShowMessage function?

Comment: @Win in $document.ready

Comment: You cannot place inside $(document).ready.

Comment: which tag is #info and  where is it??

Comment: @Suprajv just posted it now in initial question =)